# MyBatis update if a field in the source object is not null

Tags: java, sql, mybatis, dynamic-sql

Using MyBatis annotation and dynamic SQL, I was trying to update a field of a table only if the corresponding field in the source object is not null. For example, if #{srcField} is not null, set field=#{srcField}. I do not care if the field in DB is null or not.

However, I failed to come up with a correct dynamic SQL.

I tried two dynamic sql approaches. Approach 1 can be taken by my program, but it failed to check if the specific field in the source object is null. Approach 2 causes some run-time error.

My DAO object with setter/getter (source object to update the table):

```java
@Data
public class CityDO {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private String description;
}
```

Mapper using annotation and dynamic sql. I was trying to update the `description` field, only if `record.description` is not `null`.

Approach 1, it failed the test `#{description}!=null`, even if record.description==`null`. Each time the produced sql include `SET description = ?`.

```java
  @Update({
      "<script>",
        "update city",
        "<set>",
          "<if test='#{description} != null'>description = #{description,jdbcType=VARCHAR},</if>",
        "</set>",
      "where name = #{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}",
      "</script>"
  })
  @Override
  int update(CityDO record);
```

Approach 2, the only difference is I added jdbcType in the test condition. The exception is `Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'VARCHAR' in 'class com.mycode.CityDO'`

```java
"<if test='#{description,jdbcType=VARCHAR} != null'>description = #{description,jdbcType=VARCHAR},</if>",
```

I appreciate if someone can tell me how to make it working, and if there is a reference solution (even an xml-based one is fine).

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```xml
<if test='description != null'>
```

The value of `test` attribute is evaluated by OGNL while `#{}` is a MyBatis way of referencing parameter/property.
And, in your case, `jdbcType`s may be unnecessary (there is no harm, though).

Comment: It works. Originally I thought `description ` was referring to the value already in DB, so used `#{description}` instead.